# Variance of the mean following multiple steps of subsampling

Tags: variance, sampling, sample, subsampling

Let's say we have 10 sets of 1 to 4 values each. First we sample one value from each set, giving us 10 values. We then sample five of these. Lastly, we compute their average.

If one repeated this two-step subsampling and averaging procedure thousands of times, one would obtain a distribution of means. How would I go about computing the standard deviation of these means?

Comment: You might start by considering the result where you take $1$ rather than $5$ values

Comment: I'm under the impression, though correct me if I'm wrong, that the mean of the values after the first subsampling step is $$ \mu_{sub} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}\frac{X_{i}}{n_{i}} $$

And that the variance of an individual value sampled from this subsample is $$ 
\sigma_{sub}^{2} = \sum_{i} \frac{(X-\mu_{sub})^{2}}{N \cdot n_{i}} $$

Where $N$ is the number of sets, $n$ is the size of a single set, and $X$ is a single value

Comment: OK - though you might want to clarify your notation: e.g variance is usually $\sigma^2$ rather than $\sigma$ and it looks as if $X_i$ is a single potential value and $n_i$ the size of the subset $X_i$ is in so your sum is over all potential values.

Comment: I have corrected the mistakes, I hope this looks better.

$$ \mu_{sub} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i}\frac{X_{i}}{n_{i}} $$


$$ \sigma_{sub}^{2} = \sum_{i} \frac{(X_{i}-\mu_{sub})^{2}}{N \cdot n_{i}} $$

Comment: Note that your expected value for the average of $5$ values will be the same as for $1$.  Unfortunately I suspect there is nothing so simple for the variance as your $5$ are chosen without replacement from the $10$  (if they had been chosen with replacement you could simply multiply the variance by $\frac15$ - I am not quite sure your case allows this)